# Ubuntu AndroidStudio flutter: JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: bash, android-studio, flutter, ubuntu, gradle

I'm having a problem running my flutter application in android studio.

It gives me the following message

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is `echo $JAVA_HOME` and I have added the bin to my PATH

```
/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin/jdk-14.0.2
```

I can run flutter from terminal via `flutter run` after upgrading gradle from `gradle-5.6.2-all.zip` to `gradle-6.3-all.zip`

I think the problem lies in android/gradlew in the following script

```sh
# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
else
    JAVACMD="java"
    which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi
```

I tried copying it and running it and it runs with no problems with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` which is the shebang in gradlew

I tried reinstalling android studio, but it didn't work. My `flutter doctor --verbose` is a mess. At first it couldn't find android studio- said it is not installed. so I ran `flutter config --android-studio-dir="/snap/bin"` but now I get this output even though I have the plugins installed

```
:~$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    ✗ android-studio-dir = /snap/bin
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
:~$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

Thank you all hopefully I'm missing something simple!

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70497